# Android Studio Query Function how to add WHERE clause?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, android-studio

I am currently trying to display a report for out of stock items. I have the function readOutData() implemented into my report activity and it displays all of the products but how can I edit my function to only show products whose quantity is 0? Here is the code for my current function that just reads all of the product data. I added a comment showing what I want it to do, I'm just not sure how to format it.

```
Cursor readOutData() {
     String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME; //WHERE quantity = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = null;
    if(db != null){
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried and what errors are you getting?

Comment: Your comment seems to complete the statement just fine?

Comment: @HenryTwist probaly just missing a blank space before `where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work, assuming that the columns are correct

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +  " WHERE quantity = 0";
```

Although use of a PreparedStatement would be better.